# Lubuntu 12.04, what is the best method to upload pics from my Canon Powershot A520-A510

Tags: lubuntu, canon, photo-management, upload

In Lubuntu 12.04, what is the best method to upload pics from my Canon Powershot A520-A510 camera?  Do I need to install an app?  If so, which app do you recommend.  I am new to Linux, and presently settled on Lubuntu.

Comment: Does nothing happen when you plug your camera?

Answer (score 1):

Lubu!

First, I would install the lightweight photo manager called gThumb. You can install it by pasting the following code into your terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install gthumb
```

Second, you will need to connect your camera to the computer. There are a few ways to do this, depending on your camera.

- The easiest is to insert the SD card into your computer SD port (if it has one).
- The alternate way is to connect your entire camera to the computer via a USB cable.

You should see a pop-up that appears after you complete the connection above. Chose the gThumb option.

[image: Popup]

Finally, follow the import steps/options given by gThumb. Be sure your folder destination is your `home/USERNAME/Pictures` directory. That keeps your directories clean and simple.

If you did not see a popup when you connected your camera, the alternative way is to open gThumb and chose the import option (File -> Import From -> Removable Device)

[image: Import from Device]

You will again have upload options.

[image: Upload Options]

Finally, there are other options instead of gThumb that you may like. Here are [four more](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-photo-album-managers-linux/) standard options. I like gThumb because it fits Lubuntu's philosophy: (1) Lightweight and (2) Minimalist.

Enjoy your photos!